# jQuery clear inputs & change color

Tags: jquery, css, input

I am relatively new to jQuery. What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').focus(
    function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('blacktxt');
    });

    $('input[type=text]').blur(
    function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('graytxt');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: what's wrong? how wrong is the code? how doesn't it work? BTW, looks like you just need to use pure CSS for this kind of task.

Comment: Try $(this).toggleClass('blacktxt graytxt');

Comment: `input[type=text]{color:#BBB} input[type=text]:focus{color:#000}`

Comment: Extra braces if you use Visual Studio IDE use tab keys and put semicolon in end of code so that it will automatically comes next to code then your code is proper else there is some script error

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wucAp/2/

Comment: I had extra closing braces. It works not, but choppy. If I click away from the input and then back into it, it won't change color back to black. Guess I have to think about a workaround.

Comment: @user3514573 Use CSS, see my comment/[SW4's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22958623/1612146)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close extra one braces

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[type=text]').focus(
    function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('blacktxt');
    });   // focus Closed

    $('input[type=text]').blur(
    function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('graytxt');
    }); // blur closed

  });  // document ready closed
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do similar with pure CSS:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KX6BY/9/)

HTML

```
<input type='text' value='text...'/>
```

CSS

```
input:focus{
    color:red;
}
input{
    color:grey;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I also wanted to clear the inputs using jQuery, so I figured I could use it for this color change as well.

Comment: If you want to clear them, why not use the placeholder property on an input? Seems like thats the functionality you're ater

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra enclosing `});` that break the page.

If you check the console you see:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').focus(
    function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('blacktxt');
    });

    $('input[type=text]').blur(
    function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('graytxt');
    });
  });
}); // <-- remove this line
```

By removing it will work fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/kGWF9/

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LAv6v/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="text">
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="text"] {
    border:1px solid #333333;
    color: #000000;
}
input[type="text"].edit {
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    color:#666666;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Input = $('input[type=text]');
    var default_value = Input.val();

    $(Input).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == default_value) {
            $(this).val("");
            $("input").addClass("edit");
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        $("input.edit").removeClass("edit");
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $(this).val(default_value);
            $("input.edit").removeClass("edit");
        }
    });
})
```